# What is different between mongodb 4.2 vs mongodb 6.0?

Tags: mongodb

i want to know clear comparision between mongodb 4.3 and mongodb 6.0
with mongodb doc, i can find only 'Compatibility Changes in MongoDB x.0'
in this doc, i only find the difference between latest one and one before the latest one.

plz help me

Comment: Therese is no direct comparison, you have to go through the list of changes for each release.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB release notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/release-notes/) are the best place to look.

The are numerous changes between mongodb 4.3 and 6.0 .